# Помогите сделать текст на логотипе сайта

Tags: html, css, img

Помогите сделать текст на логотипе сайта как показано на рисунке. (RU).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код в котором находится логотип:

```
<div id="site-logo"><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$"><img src="/images/logo.png" width="295" height="60" border="0" alt="Cyber Land" /></a></div>
```

Заранее всем благодарен.

Comment: Сами-то поняли, в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Сделать текстом поверх картинки. Что здесь непонятного? Я же написал "сделать текст на логотипе сайта". Извиняюсь если не так выразился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На div делаете position:relative. Внутри кладёте спан с текстом "RU"(лучше изображение RU, а не текст, в логотипах делают изображением) задаёте ему позицию absolute и позиционируете на нужное место.

```
<div id="site-logo"><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$"><img src="/images/logo.png" width="295" height="60" border="0" alt="Cyber Land" /><span class="logo-text-language">RU</span></a></div> 

/styles.css 
#site-logo { 
  position: relative; 
} 

.logo-text-language { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 10px; 
   right: 15px; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне именно тектом нужно. Перменная движка будет выдавать страну с которой зашел пользователь. Она будет текстом. И мне конечно лучше бы кодом, я в стилях не очень разбираюсь, потому и прошу помощи...

Comment: Текстом тот же принцип, разницы нет

Comment: А не моглибы Вы код для примера скинуть, из того что я оставил в вопросе? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Я вам написал логику как нужно сделать, "сделайте за меня" это не очень хорошая позиция для развития, при всём уважении.

<div id="site-logo"><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$"><img src="/images/logo.png" width="295" height="60" border="0" alt="Cyber Land" /><span class="logo-text-language">RU</span></a></div>

/styles.css

#site-logo {
    position: relative;
    }
 
.logo-text-language{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    }

Comment: Спасибо, все сделал, только немного переписал по своему.